# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre Section y Article en html5 ?

Tags: html5

Necesito saber la diferencia entre una etiqueta article y una etiqueta section en html5 y cuando utilizarlo para que mi pagina sea semánticamente correcta.

Answer (score 5):

La etiqueta `<section>`:

> La etiqueta sección define las secciones de un documento, como capítulos, encabezados, pies de página o cualquier otra sección del documento.

De acuerdo con la documentación HTML5 del W3C:

> "Una sección es un agrupamiento temático de contenido, normalmente con un encabezado".

Ejemplo:

```
  <section>
    <h1>WWF</h1>
   <p>The World Wide Fund for Nature (WWF) is....</p>
  </section>
```

La etiqueta `<article>`:

> La etiqueta del article especifica contenido independiente y autónomo.
>
> Un artículo debe tener sentido por sí mismo y debería ser posible
>   Distribuirlo independientemente del resto del sitio.
>
> Fuentes potenciales para el elemento artículo:
>
> - Posts de foro
> - Blog post
> - Noticias
> - Comentarios

Ejemplo:

```
 <article>
     <h1>What Does WWF Do?</h1>
     <p>WWF's mission is to stop the degradation of our planet's natural environment, and build a future in which humans live in harmony with nature.</p>
 </article>
```

### ¿Anidamiento `<article>` en `<section>` o viceversa?

El elemento `<article>` especifica un contenido independiente y autónomo.

El elemento `<section>` define la sección en un documento.

### ¿Podemos utilizar las definiciones para decidir cómo anidar esos elementos? ¡No podemos!

Así, en Internet, encontrará páginas HTML con elementos `<section>` que contienen elementos `<article>` y `<article>` que contienen elementos `<section>`.

También encontrará páginas con elementos  que contienen elementos `<section>` y elementos `<article>` que contienen elementos `<article>`.

> Ejemplo para un periódico: Los artículos deportivos en la sección de deporte, pueden tener una sección técnica en cada artículo.

---

Básicamente estas etiquetas son *elementos semánticos* y la única diferencia real entre ellos es la legibilidad y la preferencia de diseño.

Más información:

- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp

Esto es una [traducción](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33910539/4987172).

Answer (score 0):

Sección: Elemento que representa una sección genérica (parte o pieza) de un documento.Ejemplo: Capítulos, Pestañas, Secciones y mas ...
Articulo: Elemento que representa un objeto completo en su composición y es en principio independiente y re utilizable. Ejemplo: Blog, Post de revistas, Paginas de periódico y diferentes gadgets.

Como sugerencia se usa sección para separar áreas que conforman un solo objeto mayor o de un solo tema, y se usa articulo cuando el objecto es un ente independiente y completo (o pensamos re usarlo).

Funcionalmente, ambos tags hacen lo mismo , pero semanticamente es mejor utilizar el adecuado para fines de SEO, Optimizacion, y Mantenimiento de Codigo